# Compute mean in R dependent on specific value in another variable

Tags: r, mean

I have my dataset called IMS, consisting of 11 variables.
**strong text**

I would like to compute the mean for the variable *std.y* for all observations where the variable *pi* == 1.

Anyone who can tell me how to compute this? :)

Best Regards,
Henrik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mean(IMS$std.y[IMS$pi==1])
```

This is something you can get from most introductory texts on R - I'd recommend you look through those before posting questions here.